# I can't create a qt quick control project , what I have to do

Tags: c++, qt, qtquickcontrols

I have some problems with at creator while creating a qt quick control project.
I have downloaded full version of qt, but when I wanna create a new qt quick control, I can't do this, because while creating a new project in kit selection there's no kits to choose.

**Screen shot**

[image]

I don't have this problem with quick widgets or other project just in qt quick control!!

Comment: It says right there to "Please add a kit in the options[...]". Have you tried that?

Comment: @Blaze || my probles is that i have kits while creating sidget project , but when i wanna create qt quick qontrol there's no kits !!!

Comment: What version of Qt do you have?

Comment: 5.1.1 brother ...